# Get the last select statement from a pyodbc SQL query

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am performing a long SQL query with several temp tables created along the way

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=Server;'
                      'Database=DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = """
Select *   
into #Cohort
From TABLE1

SELECT * from TABLE2 as tab2
inner join #Cohort as tab1 on tab2.id = tab1.id
"""

population = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
```

and getting the error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

From what I read it is because `read_sql_query()` only takes the first `SELECT` statement. 
How do I specify what `SELECT` statement to return using it or another function?

Comment: Put `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the very beginning of your SQL text.

Answer (score 0):

Worked by adding SET NOCOUNT ON;

Thanks Gord Thompson!